# pyinstaller not run part of the code selecting noconsole or windowed option

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, win32com

I developed couple of python scripts that right now i'm going to join in a **tkinter** gui.
To makes this simple application user-friendly and portable for my collegues, I'm using **pyInstaller** to pack everything in a compiled exe file.

Everything works fine as far as I don't try to hide console with **--noconsole** or **--windowed**.

In this case just part of the script does not produce expected output.

Compare with the other part of the code, I can notice that this part uses **win32com.client** to process an **excel** file while the other works on plain text.

Have anybody experienced something like this?

Thanks, Ale_Trex.

Comment: I met this problem,too when I use `pyexecjs` to change the `Javascript` environment.

Comment: Hi there,Did you solved some way?

Comment: I have no idea.